# Disabling refresh and showtasks button in publishing queue window during request

Tags: 2013-sp1, gui-extensions

Good morning!

We noticed that our clients press the refresh button and/or show tasks button in the publishing queue screen repeatedly if they don't get a response fast enough.
Every time these buttons are pressed new requests are being sent to our database.

Is there a way to temporarily disable these buttons when a database request is pending?
I've found an [extension build](http://monicamanzano.blogspot.com/2012/11/load-queue-override-gui-extension.html) by Monica Manzano (SDL), but unfortunately this is built for Tridion 2011 and it's not working in Tridion 2013 SP1.
If you could give use some tips on how to make the extension Tridion 2013 SP1 compatible then this would be the best solution as this extension does exactly what we are looking for.

Kind regards and many thanks in advance,

Koen

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing out of the box. In this instance I'd recommend looking to update the GUI Extension (maybe even utilising the [Alchemy](https://www.alchemywebstore.com) framework). The core s

You could also consider the existing Alchemy Plugin for the "[Real-Time Publish Queue](https://www.alchemywebstore.com/plugins/Real-Time-Publish-Queue)"